# What documents required in order to pass by car from Russia to Mongolia?

Tags: paperwork, spain, insurance, mongolia, carnet-de-passage

For example, a Spanish citizen with his 1971 S.E.A.T. 124 (Spanish-made fiat 124), is travelling from Spain to Mongolia via France, Italy, Slovenia, Croatia, Serbia, Bulgaria, Turkey, Georgia, Azerbaijan (crossing to Central Asia is made by ferry across the Caspian Sea from the Port of Baku), then Kazakhstan, Russia and finally via the Russian/Mongolian border crossing to Ulaanbaatar. The car has Spanish registration number plates and renewed vehicle registration certificate.

So, what documents of the car required at the Russian/Mongolian border crossing alongside the Spanish passport? Does Mongolia recognize carnet de passage? Are border insurance required at the Mongolian customs?

Answer (score 1):

[Information in Russian and going back to 2013](http://www.svali.ru/stories/64/0/3145/index.htm) not mentioning anything except the passports and visas and possible XRay of your bags.

Similar information is available from [Legend Tours (in Russian)](http://www.legendtour.ru/rus/mongolia/auto/border_crossing.shtml) with similar information.  Basically you will need to have a proof of ownership of the car or a legal document allowing you to drive it, the usual visas still apply.  There is also no mention of any specific insurance requirements for border crossings.